# Post Confirmation doesn't trigger lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

My step:

- I created user  by calling the AdminCreateUser API.
- I use my custom login form to do the first login
- I change password (because I'm in FORCE_PASSWORD_CHANGE status)
  Now the user is CONFIRMED
- Trigger doesn't fire.

Comment: Did you find out why that happened? Facing the same problem!

Answer (score 8):

Cognito does not trigger post confirm when the user is created with `adminCreateUser` or manually from Cognito dashboard.

Comment: Do you have any documentation proving that ? I'm not challenging your response. It totally makes sense, since well, is not getting triggered in my case as well, but is there anywhere in AWS where we can get that info from ?

Comment: The Cognito documents are quite poor. I have myself been exploring this for a bit and I can confirm this with my exploration. I have tested both scenarios and this is how it is.

Comment: This is correct, the adminCreateUser doesn't trigger the post confirm event. You can however trigger pre-sign up, check my other answer to this question for details and references.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is correct. I've tried all of the configurations. Here's a list of those triggers that work: Pre Sign Up, Pre Authentication, Post Authentication. 

I've tried unticking the "confirm phone" and "confirm email" radio boxes, but it still won't work. I'm doing the same, and I need the user to provide data so that I can use the Lambda to pop that info into a db. This is too bad.

Comment: @Bennybear I need your exact behavior too. Actually, I need to set up a whole tenant for the user in that trigger.

How'd you get around this quickly? signup on hosted UI?

Comment: @ShawnMclean I created a signup script using the AWS CLI and used the Pre Sign Up trigger. I then used my Lambda to do my trickery. If you want to grab user info after they're done authenticating (after they submit a code or something) for your lambda, the best path is a signup using Amplify or the cognito identity SDK and using the Post Auth trigger. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the answer to this as well and I found this in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html):-

> You create custom workflows by assigning AWS Lambda functions to user
> pool triggers. When you use the AdminCreateUser API action, Amazon
> Cognito invokes the function that is assigned to the ***pre sign-up
> trigger***. When Amazon Cognito invokes this function, it passes a JSON
> payload, which the function receives as input.

So basically we need to attach the lambda function to the pre sign-up trigger if we are using the AdminCreateUser API action. Haven't checked if it works. Confirmation would be great!

Update:-

I tried it out myself and it does trigger the pre sign-up lambda function. So there's the confirmation!

Comment: But that does not imply that the user really change his password. Just that it was created

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, it is post "confirmation" trigger. The user needs to confirm the email belongs to him/her. This is done by entering the OTP that cognito sends to the given email address. Once the user enters that OTP, the email address is confirmed and post confirmation trigger fires.

Do
Use the hosted UI's "Signup" link to create the account

Do Not
Use Cognito service's in-built user creation page.
Use Admin API